# What is inode number of lost + found directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, inode, lost-found

I used this to find the inodes, but can't locate lost + found in it

```
find . -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how i get the inode number of my `/tmp` partition on a host i manage

```
host1:~# cd /tmp/
host1:/tmp# ls -id lost+found
    11 lost+found
```

However, there is no "fixed number" of inode to `lost+found` dir. It happens to be the first directory to be created after you make the filesystem on a partition, having the value of `11` assigned, cause it is the first non-reserved inode available.

Digging at the [ext4 documentation](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Special_inodes), you can find this index of special inode numbers

- `0` - Doesn't exist; there is no inode 0.
- `1` - List of defective blocks.
- `2` - Root directory.
- `3` - User quota.
- `4` - Group quota.
- `5` - Boot loader.
- `6` - Undelete directory.
- `7` - Reserved group descriptors inode. ("resize inode")
- `8` - Journal inode.
- `9` - The "exclude" inode, for snapshots(?)
- `10` - Replica inode, used for some non-upstream feature?
- `11` - Traditional first non-reserved inode. Usually this is the lost+found directory. See s_first_ino in the superblock